# Coefficients in sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, regression, logistic-regression

I am watching the MIT open course for python and data science, 6.0002. It was teaching logistic regression in lecture 13. Here is the code:

```
import sklearn.linear_model

def buildModel(examples, toPrint = True):
    featureVecs, labels = [],[]
    for e in examples:
        featureVecs.append(e.getFeatures())
        labels.append(e.getLabel())
    LogisticRegression = sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression
    model = LogisticRegression().fit(featureVecs, labels)
    if toPrint:
        print('model.classes_ =', model.classes_)
        print('model.coef_ =', model.coef_)
        for i in range(len(model.coef_)):
            print('For label', model.classes_[1])
            for j in range(len(model.coef_[0])):
                print('   ', Passenger.featureNames[j], '=',
                      model.coef_[0][j])
    return model

model = buildModel(trainingSet, True)
```

And here is the output:

```
model.classes_ = ['Died' 'Survived']
model.coef_ = [[ 1.63216725  0.4504459  -0.52476792 -0.03218074 -2.29930577]]
For label Survived
    C1 = 1.63216724529
    C2 = 0.450445901238
    C3 = -0.524767915254
    age = -0.0321807370827
    male gender = -2.29930576947
```

I have two question:

1. Why model.coef_ only has one element while model.classes_ has two? Shouldn't their lengths match?
2. Why the values of model.coef_ are the coefficients of label "Survived" instead of label "Died"? I mean if the order of elements in model.classes_ and model.coef_ are identical, the numbers in coef_ should be for label "Died", right? Since "Died" comes first.

Thanks!

Comment: By looking at the official sklearn docs it is correct that the coef_ has shape (1, n_features). Please look http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html

Comment: @primef Thanks! I saw it is of shape (1, n_features) when the labels are binary. And mine has two labels, it should be the case. But how about my second question? Which label is coef_[0] for? classes_[0] or classes_[1]? It does not say

Comment: Moreover you are training a single classifier so that the coefficients you get are for the whole classifier. Instead if you would have a multi class problem, you would train multiple classifiers (standard sklearn in this case is one-vs-all). Therefore in the multi class case you would have as much coef_ arrays as classifiers.

Comment: Please review your code I think you made a typo. When you print the model.classes_ you use [1], in my opinion you should use [i]. Moreover you use fixed values to access the array. Why are you not using the i and j variable of the two loops? Correct me please if I’m wrong.

Comment: @primef I copied from the course material. If it were wrong, it would be really interesting. It is an MIT course, and the professor use the output to make some conclusions. The whole discussion after this typo would be wrong, because the conclusion becomes the opposite!

Comment: I’m really not sure why they are making a loop over the length of the coef_ array (the first loop) if they then never use the i variable for anything and they always print the same. So if coef_ would have two arrays in it, they are still printing the String survived but potentially with different values for the coefficients. Which would result in a contradiction. I’m not sure if I’m not seeing something, because I never watched the course maybe they give a reason for they programming choice. The only thing I can imagine is that they programmed this code so that it can apply only 1/2

Comment: 2/2 to binary classification problems. Therefore they could have done the assumption that the coefficient will EVERYTIME have only one array in it. The second assumption which derives from that is that they choose a class to be the positive one, in this case the survived one, and associated the coefficients to it. However at this point I’m just making some hypothesis and assumptions myself, because as said I never watched those MIT course and don’t have knowledge of how they justify their approach.

Comment: @primef I believe you made a great point! Why the coefficients are for the positive one? Can you refer me to some literature about it? It is justified by common sense I guess. The data are from Titanic survivors. The conclusion are like people in 1st class cabin have a better chance to survive and ladies have a better chance to survive etc. If it were a typo, the conclusion would be opposite and really confusing

Comment: Unfortunately I don’t have any specific literature at hand right now that I can give you. However it is the way logistic regression works. It gives you the probability that you example is a 1, the positive class. You can then retrieve the probability of it being a negative class by doing 100-h(x) where h(x) is the prediction of you classifier. It is also the way Andrew Ng has explained it in his course Machine Learning on Coursera. It is by far one of the best entry points for Machine Learning and would give you a good start and some intuition on it. 1/2

Comment: 2/2 If I find some literature on the fact that we always consider the positive class and if there are any mathematical reasons I will comment this post. However I hope your question is partially cleared. Summarizing you cannot expect the coefficients to be different for every class as you are training only a binary classifier, so that the coef_ you get is for the whole classifier function and not specific of a single class (only valid for binary classification). Those coefs are associated with the positive class.

Comment: Part 3/2: I found something about literature, it is only a quora forum question but I hope it can be a starting point for your future research on the topic. https://www.quora.com/Why-is-the-output-of-logistic-regression-interpreted-as-a-probability . As it seems it is the mathematical formula of logistic regression that considers the positive case.

Comment: @primef Thanks for your help! I need some time to read it! But why "Died" is a negative class and "Survived" is a positive one? Assumed by their positions in classes_? I also need to check out what negative/positive class means. I am totally a newbie

Comment: as said please give the Machine Learning course on Coursera a try. It will introduce you gently and give you a strong background. However I assume it is done by the positioning in classes_ but am not sure. In a binary classification as yours you have only two classes, hence two cases your classifier needs to recognize. Call them how you want: 0/1, off/on, negative/positive... In the Machine Learning community they are referenced as positive and negative. They don’t have much of a context in some cases. They don’t have to mean that a class is positive, good, or negative, bad.

Comment: @primef Thanks. But I still can't decide which label would be a positive class before the program runs and prints out the contents of class_. Actually, I just checked the first record read by the program is a survivor, so the first label learnt by the program is "Survive" and should be the first element in classes_. However it is the second label in class_. It is confusing.

Comment: I’m sorry but I don’t know how they choose the positive and negative classes. At a first look on the documentation I didn’t discover anything. Maybe one should look deeply in the sklearn docs. Somewhere they will explain it. They could choose the label type on base of different type of things. For example not only the position but how many times a class is present in the training data. Or maybe in some other implicit way.

Comment: Please take also into consideration that the training data maybe, and in most of the cases it is done automatically, is shuffled. So that the “first” example used for training is defined only at runtime.

Comment: No. `classes_` will be alphabetically sorted orded. And the `coef_` are for the features, not labels. In case of binary classification, they will be dot multiplied with the feature values and a single score is generated. If that score is greater than 0, then classes_[1] is selected else classes_[0]. Nothing related in positive, negative in a broader sense